# How can query in FMDB while it's in an huge updating task

Tags: ios, objective-c, fmdb

Please see my code below.

In our requirement, we have a lot of db updates at the beginning,
As I understand,
I doubt if the task A will let B wait until A is finished. if it works as I am saying, then I hope the Task A can be paused and I do Task B, that will be perfect

DO I understand correctly?

It will be great if I can query as B whenever I want and don't ***wait*** A finished. (the old DB is not empty, even not updated, it can be in use)

Thanks!

```
FMDatabaseQueue *queue = [[FMDatabaseQueue alloc]init];
// A
[queue inDatabase:^(FMDatabase *db, BOOL *rollback) { 
    //a huge amount of inserts and updates
}];

// B
[queue inDatabase:^(FMDatabase *db, BOOL *rollback) { 
    // some easy querying task
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you initiate two Queues at the same time and If it access same table then there may be chance of Deadlock occurrence.

`FMDatabaseQueue` will run the blocks on a serialized queue. So if you call FMDatabaseQueue's methods from multiple threads at the same time, they will be executed in the order they are received.

**Note**: The calls to FMDatabaseQueue's methods are blocking. So even though you are passing along blocks, they will not be run on another thread.

Comment: Without FMDatabaseQueue. Is there an alternative way to fix my problem?

Comment: It is better to use FMDatabaseQueue as its create queue and manage threads as well while execution.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest working on a clone version of your database. If update task -> clone database by copy file, point reading path to clone version and points reading path to the original DB when finished update. But you should handle another thing like merge data when you make a change on working copy

Comment: I think it works but it costs too much. I believe web server developers don't  do that to fix problems like mine. There must be a better solution